# text formula =TEXT(A1,"mm/dd") results to 00/dd

Tags: microsoft-excel-365, date-format

I am trying to convert the date to text.
First, I tried =TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy") and the result is 00/dd/yyyy. From what I read in some forums, I could replace 'yyyy' with 'e' and that solved half of the problem. Still, I can't seem to find a fix for the date and month though.
My Windows language is the same as the preferred language in my Excel application.

Answer (score 1):

I have long assumed that `mm` is for minutes, and `MM` for months, unless your chosen LANGUAGE defines it in any other way. (e.g. a Swedish Excel has ÅÅÅÅ where the English has YYYY).

Now this is WRONG, it is always "mm" and APPARENTLY the CONTEXT determines which to print; e.g. "dd" close before or behind => mm is months, hh just before => mm is minutes.

*To determine what your Excel requires:*
Search for "format codes" in the help,
there might be a link to them in the help text for the `TEXT()`-function.

---

Based on the comments:

`=TEXT(A1,"mm")` or `=TEXT(A1,"MM")` will always(?) print a double digit MONTH, i.e. it is not POSSIBLE to single out the MM portion of `=TEXT(A1,"hh:MM")` unless you do `=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hh:MM"),2)`

Now from this I conclude that Excel was not able to determine whether it should be minutes or months in the format use in the question - therefore "00" as result.

Comment: mm is minutes 00-59 in a time, and months 00-12 in a date.

Comment: Yes!? They need to be distinct from each other; you may have BOTH in the same time and day value. That is why month is encoded with M's.

Comment: cell A1: `2020-05-27  07:15:46` formula: `=TEXT(A1,"dd:mm hh:mm")` result: `27:05 07:15`

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68 - *sigh* found yet another braindead microsoft-ism.